# Enterprise Architect: How to show packages as groups in a diagram

Tags: enterprise-architect

I'm trying to import some source code into EA, and make packages. In my root class diagram, I want to show each package as a visual grouping and have all classes inside that package in one group.

Can this be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not automatically. When you reverse-engineer source code, you have the option of creating either one class diagram in each package, or no diagrams at all.

Doing it manually, you can create a diagram which simply contains the packages: by default, EA lists the contents of each package when the package is placed in a diagram.

You could also drag the classes into the diagram and group them using boundaries or swimlanes. Boundaries are created from the "Common" diagram toolbox, while swimlanes are accessed by right-clicking an empty area of the diagram.

Finally, you can play around with the diagram's properties (also accessed by right-clicking an empty area), specifically the ones concerning namespaces and fully-scoped object names; these affect how EA displays packages and elements in a diagram.